# DoubleAnimation playing by itself, or wrongfully triggered?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have 2 DoubleAnimations that bring the ToastNotification in, and put it back outside of the window. However, it seems to be just skipping that there's a delay between **ToastIN** and **ToastOUT**.

*XAML*

```xml
<Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ToastIN">
            <DoubleAnimation From="501" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="Toast" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ToastOUT">
            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="501" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetName="Toast" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
```

*CS*

```cs
void ShowToast(string Header, string Content)
            {
                ToastHeader.Text = Header;
                ToastContent.Text = Content;

                Storyboard ToastIN = (Storyboard)FindResource("ToastIN");
                ToastIN.Begin();

                Task.Delay(3500);

                Storyboard ToastOUT = (Storyboard)FindResource("ToastOUT");
                ToastOUT.Begin();
            }
```

Comment: You need to wait for the Task Delay, so you either need to `await Task.Delay(3500);` or you need `Task.Delay(3500).Wait();`  if your method is not marked as `async`.

Comment: @quaabaam thanks, the .Wait(); didn't work but i forgot i changed my method from async because I was testing with it.